# Broken man pages

Tags: manpage

All man pages seem to be broken on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

I tried to reinstall (with purge) the man-db package, but that doesn't help.

Man pages look like -->

[image: this].

The description is ok, but flags and commands are missing.

Comment: What is your terminal colour scheme set to?

Comment: Did you mes with your LESS_TERMCAP vars?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open Profile Preferences from Terminal global Edit menu and under "Colors" tab you will see like this:

[image]

The problem is that your "Background color" and "Bold color" are the same color. Change one of them to different one OR You can check the "Same as text color" for bold color to fix that.

Comment: Hah. The most tough errors are the most primitive. )

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your bold font. Everything but the bold letters are rendered correctly.

In the terminal settings try setting another font or check `same as text color` for bold color.

If that fixes the problem, use another font or reinstall the fonts (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console`).

Comment: Why should installing Microsoft-Fonts help with an Ubuntu terminal issue?

Comment: Whats the correct package of fonts which, are used in the terminal, to reinstall?

Comment: The default terminal in Ubuntu uses the *Ubuntu Mono* font, which is provided by `fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console` package.

Comment: If the fonts are already installed, this won't do anything. It should be `sudo apt-get install --reinstall <packagelist>`